# variable redeclared in else inside for printing always the same

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli

I need to print some db data into a html list. If I redeclare a variable in else, previously declared in if, will print only the value from else variable...

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
    $month = 'month' . $i;
    if($row[$month] == 1) {
        $paid[] = 'Pagado';
        $bonus = $row['bonus'];
        //$cashed = 
    } else {
        $paid[] = 'No Pagado';
        $bonus = '0'; // $bonus will print always this, even if the if is true.
        $cashed = 'No';
    }
}
//Now make the HTML list

foreach($monthNames as $key => $month) {
    echo '
            <div class="list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="month">' . $month . '</a></li>
                    <li><a class="status">' . $paid[$key] .'</a></li>
                    <li><a class="bonus">' . $bonus . '</a></li>
                    <li><a class="cashed">' . $cashed . '</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>';
}
```

Printing $bonus from else should be only if else is executing, but when the if is true should print db column data instead of the redeclared value.

I can't see anything wrong, why is always printing 0 instead of $row['bonus']; when $row[$month] == 1??

Thanks!

Comment: maybe your $row['bonus'] equals to '0' as well

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: Hmm if I comment $bonus from else will print the db data: column bonus is 5. Why if I redeclare $bonus in else will only print that? Is happening the same for other variables like $cashed. If I redeclare a variable inside else the html list will show only the redeclared variable (from else).

Comment: @Machavity I'm going to try it.

Comment: The $row is okey, I can see all the columns printed by var_dump(). The problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are printing $bonus after for loop, then variable $bonus will depends only on $row['month12'], becouse it is saved at the end of loop.

If you want to store $bonus status for each month you should save it to array (like $paid[]).

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
    $month = 'month' . $i;
    if($row[$month] == 1) {
        $paid[] = 'Pagado';
        $bonus[] = $row['bonus'];
        //$cashed = 
    } else {
        $paid[] = 'No Pagado';
        $bonus[] = '0'; // $bonus will print always this, even if the if is true.
        $cashed[] = 'No';
    }
}
```

Then you will have $bonus array which will keep "bonus" state for each month. $bonus[0] will have bonus status for 1'st month (January), $bonus[1] for February etc.

Html list:

```
foreach($monthNames as $key => $month) {
    echo '
            <div class="list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="month">' . $month . '</a></li>
                    <li><a class="status">' . $paid[$key] .'</a></li>
                    <li><a class="bonus">' . $bonus[$key] . '</a></li>
                    <li><a class="cashed">' . $cashed[$key] . '</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>';
}
```